# Image view not reloading

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6.1

vc2 seques to vc3. In vc3 the camera can take a photo or you can delete the image. Println shows the newly taken image's name correctly when I take a new photo, then use back button to vc2. But vc2 does not update the image view unless I toggle to vc3 and back again. It does update correctly to theDefaultImg if the image was just deleted.

```
 @IBOutlet weak var thImg: UIImageView!

 override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
      super.viewWillAppear(true)
      var nuImg = delegate?.itemObChosen?.valueForKey("image2Show") as? NSString!
      println("nuImg equals \(nuImg!)")

      if (nuImg! == "" || nuImg! == nil) {
          thImg.image = UIImage(named: theDefaultImg)
      }
      else {
          thImg.image = UIImage(named: nuImg!)
      }
  }
```

Console shows:
nuImg equals 20141125183020.png which is the correct image file name (of course it changes whenever I take a new photo, but it updates correctly)

Comment: Can you show us what exactly  println("nuImg equals \(nuImg!)") prints?

Comment: It sounds like you have a bigger issue at hand here. The concept of vc2 -> vc3 -> do something -> report back to vc2 is easily solved by the delegate pattern or the use of closures (blocks). I would look at the state of your view controllers and see if you're allocating and deallocating your objects correctly.

Comment: Fixed by tweaking logic in several areas, but also by setting image outlet.image to nil before loading. Also, deleting the original thIng outlet, then creating a fresh one.